# Is there a way to add leading/trailing spaces to item in concatenate function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I am trying to bring together several cells and they have a specific length so if I have

```
A1 needs to be 5 chars and the value is 'cat' 
B1 needs to be 6 chars and the value is 'dog' 
Concatenated it would be:
[space space]cat[space space space]dog
or
"  cat   dog"
```

I'm having trouble finding a function or set of functions that allows this, most want to trim out leading or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Yes:

```
=CONCATENATE(RIGHT(REPT(" ",5)&A1,5),RIGHT(REPT(" ",6)&A2,6))
```

or as @BigBen stated use `&` instead of Concatenate:

```
=RIGHT(REPT(" ",5)&A1,5)&RIGHT(REPT(" ",6)&A2,6)
```

Comment: Or just drop the CONCATENATE for `&`: `=RIGHT(REPT(" ",5)&A1,5)&RIGHT(REPT(" ",6)&B1,6)`.

Comment: @BigBen, If you ever feel the desire to improve any of my questions, feel free to do so.  There are a few people on this board that I trust and give them blank permission to do so.  You would be one of those.  And if you feel that your improvement merits it go ahead and make it a community wiki.

Comment: Your comment just made my day!

Comment: For fun: `=CONCAT(RIGHT("      "&A1:B1,{5,6}))`